# For-loop for retrieving fonts in python zero output

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, directory, os.walk

Following code creates a folder and an image inside every folder for every character so i have 36 folders for 36 characters. character are in different fonts so far i have used 4 font for which i was pasting paths one by one but now i have almost 200 fonts, so i tried a `for loop` for retrieving every `font` but it doesn't output anything. Following code printing all font names but not creating any image.
total 36 folders inside main folder.

```
Dataset:\(36 folders)
        character(1):\
                   200 images for 200 fonts  
        character(2):\
                   200 images for 200 fonts
        ...............
        character(36):\
                   200 images for 200 fonts

list_of_letters = list (unicode_text) 
folder = 1 
n=1 
i=0
for word in itertools.permutations( list_of_letters,n): 
    char = u''.join(word) 
    t1 = arabic_reshaper.reshape(char) 
    W,H= (100, 100)
    img= PIL.Image.new('RGBA', (W, H), (255, 255, 255),)
    draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(img)   
        # font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype( r"C:\Users\Sumayyah\Downloads\arabic-typesetting\arabtype.ttf", 40)
    path=r'E:\Dummy\fonts'
    directory = os.fsencode(path)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)
            if filename.endswith(".ttf"):
                print(os.path.join(path, filename))
                continue
                for i in range(158):
                    draw.font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(path, filename), 44)
                    t2 = get_display(t1) 
                    w, h = draw.textsize(t2)
                    draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2),t2, fill="#000000")
                    path = 'E:\Dummy\Old\\'+ str(folder)
                    if not os.path.exists(path):
                      os.makedirs(path)
                    img.save(path + '\\' + char+str(i)+'.png', "PNG")
                    i+=1
                    folder += 1
```

Comment: You should be iterating over the `files` that `os.walk()` gives you, not the `dirs`...

Comment: no it doesnt work